My wifi ssid not even showing up to any of my devices
So I bought my router on 25 April 2024, it is " Mercusys MW325R v3".It was going perfectly fine until 06 may 2024 in the morning around 8 to 10 am, when i woke up and turn on wifi in my phone , my wifi ssid named "AR 47" is not even showing up in my phone.
I quickly checked my router and onu and it was all ok, all the necessary led was on like no problem, but i refreshed a few time in my phone so that i can find the ssid to connect but failed. Then i opened my laptop and same thing happened also, there was no sign of my ssid in the laptop also. Then i decided to restart the router.
So i disconnected the power and moments later i turned the router back on, and it was instantly showing ssid in both of my devices.
Then in 12 may 2024, same thing happened again. I used perfectly fine all night, but when i woke up at around 0930 am and tried to connect to both of my phone and laptop, the ssid wasn't showing up.
The again i restarted the router and then instantly it showed up and gets connected to my devices. I don't understand what seemed to be the problem. Isn't it a burden to restart the router every time?? Suppose i have gone for a few days, if then it happens, the house is locked, who will restart the router to show backe the ssid again to connect??(nb: i share it with my neighbour)How will they connect??
is my router faulty?? do i need to upgrade the firmware of my router to latest one??

Yes, you may need a firmware update. Yes, it may be faulty.

no I owned the router.but where to see the logs?
